# data only gets loaded every third time or so

Tags: angular

I have a 2 selecters i would like to get populated with data from a mysql table.

my selecters is getting the data added every 3rd or 4th time leaving me to think its because my HTML is getting rendered before data is loaded from the database.

i tried to surround my HTML with:

```
<div *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
</div>
```

This does not seems to help much if something at all.

i then tried to rerender my table with some Javascript and was able to add items but running over my array and adding them with javascript seems like the wrong way of doing this?

my selecters look like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Person</label>
        <select #person id="personselector" class="m_selectpicker form-control m-bootstrap-select--solid" data-live-search="true">
        <option value="">
            Person  
        </option>                               
        <option *ngFor="let person of persons" [value]="person.id">
            {{person.firstname}}
        </option>                               
        </select>
</div>
```

Is there someway i can secure that the data will get added to my dropdowns?

getting my data here and they are showing in the console correctly.

```
fillDropdowns(){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('payingcustomerID', '1');       
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

   this.http.post('XXX',body,{headers: headers}).map(response => response.json())
   .subscribe(data => {

    this.companies = data.companies;
    this.persons = data.persons;

    console.log(this.companies);
    console.log(this.persons);      
   })  
}
```

here is where i call my method

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.fillDropdowns();
}
```

This work in javascript

```
 for(let person of this.persons){
        myExtObject.func2(person.id,person.firstname);          
     } 

    for(let company of this.companies){
        myExtObject.func3(company.id,company.name);          
    }
    myExtObject.func4();
```

javascript code

```
func2: function(value, desc) {      
    $("#personselector").append('<option value="'+value+'" selected="">'+desc+'</option>');     
},

func3: function(value,desc) {       
    $("#companyselector").append('<option value="'+value+'" selected="">'+desc+'</option>');        
},  
func4: function() {     
    $("#personselector").selectpicker("refresh");
    $("#companyselector").selectpicker("refresh");

    $('#personselector').val('');
    $('#personselector').selectpicker('render');
    $('#companyselector').val('');
    $('#companyselector').selectpicker('render');         
}
```

Comment: check if you don't have specified ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in component declaration object

Answer (score 0):

Modify the fillDropdowns method as below

```
fillDropdowns(){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('payingcustomerID', '1');       
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

  return this.http.post('XXX',body,{headers: headers}).map(response => response.json())
   )  
}
```

Just let it return a plain observable and don't subscribe inside it.
And in your call from ngOnInit subscribe to this method

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.fillDropdowns().subscribe(data => {

        this.companies = data.companies;
        this.persons = data.persons;

        console.log(this.companies);
        console.log(this.persons);      
       };

}
```

That will solve the issue.

Comment: Had it added in my constructor, but trying with init does not help me either.

Comment: Can you check in your browser console network tab, when you refresh , what is the status of the post request from fillDropDowns, is it 200 before the page loads or pending?

Comment: seems like my fullDropDowns are the latest thing getting called. im using ngAfterViewInit() to init a datatable on the site. Not sure how to be surgent about the status at exact time

Comment: You should also make your http requests in services, for your code to be better structured, and inject your service in your component

Comment: @B.Julien You are right, it was modified to keep OP's original code changes minimal

Comment: Really appreciate your help, think i will need to read about how to inject services. i have added my javascript that works. But still cant make it load my data with angular consistant